# How can I stop my loop at number +/- 10 instead of stopping at the number 10?

Tags: javascript, loops

As shown in the code below, my loop will carry on forever.

I want the program to take the users input and `add` or `subtract` 10 based on whether they say `up` or `down` by using increments and decrements.

Any hints or help would be amazing! Thank you in advance.

```html
function runprogram() {
 var thenumber=prompt('Give me a number to increment or decrement!')
 var updown=prompt('Should I increment it up or down?')
 var thenumberup= (thenumber + 10)
 var thenumberdown=(thenumber - 10)
 
 var i; 
  
  if(updown == 'up') {
   
   for(i = thenumber; i < 10; i++) { 
  alert(i);
   }
  }
  
  if(updown == 'down') {
   for (i = thenumber; i > 10 ; i--) {
  alert(i); 
    
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the first prompt call is not a number, you must coerce it to a number with `+prompt('...')`.

As [@Adrián](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2951143/adri%c3%a1n) [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053371/how-can-i-stop-my-loop-at-number-10-instead-of-stopping-at-the-number-10/53053546#comment93006716_53053546), the comparisons should also be `<=` and `>=` otherwise it will stop directly before the target number.

```js
function runprogram() {
  var thenumber = +prompt('Give me a number to increment or decrement!')
  var updown = prompt('Should I increment it up or down?')
  var thenumberup = (thenumber + 10)
  var thenumberdown = (thenumber - 10)

  var i;
  if (updown == 'up') {
    for (i = thenumber; i <= thenumberup; i++) {
      alert(i);
    }
  }

  if (updown == 'down') {
    for (i = thenumber; i >= thenumberdown; i--) {
      alert(i);
    }
  }
}

runprogram();
```

Comment: Apparently so! This fixed it all, thank you. Also, I never knew that about the prompts thank you for this.

Comment: The condition should be less/greater or equal so that the alert shows the last number added/subtracted (5 + 10 = 15, not 14). :)

Answer (score 1):

While you've got an answer that does what you need, I find it a little dissatisfying that you have two loops. Here's another way you could do this with a single loop (by storing a multiplier depending on the direction given):

```js
function run() {
  var number = +prompt('number', 0)
  var direction = prompt('up or down?', 'up')
  var multiplier = direction === 'up' ? 1 : -1
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    alert(number + (i * multiplier));
  }
}

run();
```